# Android SQLite query to get closest location to a given longitude and latitude from a big dataset?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have about `15,000` records of longitude and latitude locations in my table and I want to select the top 10 that are closest to the user's `longitude and latitude`.

How should I approach this?

I don't think I can do a bounding box because it would take too long for the query to finish. So I am lost at what else I can do.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried running the query yet? how long is it taking?

Comment: that is long, I have used sqlite for large datasets but in a different environment, on Android they have always been small datasets. Is it one query that you are running or multiple? You can try dividing your dataset into smaller chunks and query accordingly.

Comment: have you considered breaking the dataset into smaller chunks and only searching against the ones that are applicable to the search?